# WCF response by event

Tags: c#, wcf, events

Can u help me on following task.
Exists WCF Service with method and list, where sending parameters of method. Each element of list have event. Need to send response from WCF when event of element of list rising. Exapmle below.

```
//We have this service 

    public SomeObject BeginSampleMethod(string param1, string param2)
            {
                 CommandController(param1, param2);
                 QueueManager.List[param1].EventRising+=(a,e)=>
                 {
                      //how to do this?
                      return new SomeObject(a,e);
                 }

            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WCF works off of a request -> response design. What you are trying to do will not work unless you hold the thread... and wait indefinitely. This will, in most scenarios force a timeout on the operation and generate an exception in your client invocation. You could optionally define a [duplex contract](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-create-a-duplex-contract) on your service and retain an operation context instance to do a callback when the event fires. This will only work if you retain the client instance and don't recycle your proxy client.